# How to use ruby method .present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method like this in rails app:

```
def current_user
        return @current_user if @current_user.present?
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

I haven't used the `.present?` method before so I went into my interactive ruby shell to play around with it.

Whenever I use `xxx.present?` it returns a NoMethodError. It doesn't matter if `xxx` is a string, number, array anything.

How can I use this method?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`present` is a method provided by `ActiveSupport`. It is not a part of core ruby. That is why you are not able to use it in the ruby shell. To play around with it, you will need to require the relevant libraries in your console (e.g. irb / pry):

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

This way, you will have access to all the utility methods provided by `activesupport`.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that if `@current_user.present?` is true the second line of the method will not run? i.e. `@current_user` will be returned from the first line?

Comment: Yes. The function will return @current_user from the first line.

Comment: You can also write it in one line: @current_user ||= current_user_session && current_user_session.record

Comment: Had to also require the specific extensions. In my case I required all of them to have this work.
`require 'active_support'`
`require 'active_support/core_ext'`

Answer (score 11):

[present](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) is a rails method, not ruby.
try using `rails c` instead of `irb` to use it in your console.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, `.present` is not in the ruby standard library. Instead, it's in active_support ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F).)

To use active_support, first install the gem, then require it in irb or your ruby script. More information on how to selectively load activesupport extensions can be found in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-all-objects).